# SH script is not inserting the user input variables

Tags: shell, sh, robotframework

Below is the script im trying to execute from the terminal. User prompts are being ask as they should, however, seems likes its not including them on the last command
My script is below

```
!/bin/bash


read -p "Enter URL:"  url
read -p "Enter Username:"  username
read -p "Enter Password:"  password



COMMAND robot -v BROWSER:Chrome -v USERNAME:$username -v PASSWORD:$password -v URL:$url -d Results Tests/robotscript_App.robot
```

I tried adding double quotes to the variables within the command section but no luck.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [**5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time). It worth bookmarking the guides [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)  (especially the Pitfalls `:)` along with [**shellcheck.net**](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the `COMMAND` it should run fine.

And you better add a `#` to your shebang on first line.

```
#!/bin/bash


read -p "Enter URL:"  url
read -p "Enter Username:"  username
read -p "Enter Password:"  password



robot -v BROWSER:Chrome -v USERNAME:$username -v PASSWORD:$password -v URL:$url -d Results Tests/robotscript_App.robot
```